# Ctrl+f5 реализовать программно в SGWT

Tags: smartgwt, java

Доброго времени суток. Сам я человек новый в этом, помогите, кто знает.
Как средствами sgwt реализовать в коде Ctrl+f5, к примеру, в firefox позволяет ещё очистить кэш. Конечно можно использовать Windows.open (хотя это gwt`шный класс), но думаю, что он кэш не почистит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очистку кэша на клиенте средствами JS (а значит и xGWT), скорее всего, не удастся.

Если вам это нужно, чтобы убедиться, что на клиенте последняя версия приложения, то все проще. GWT после каждой компиляции генерирует случайные имена для частей приложения, которые должны обновляться. Вроде такого:

```
93DEFCB335F0BAE2F88A9A53CEC6CBF2.cache.html
```

Эти файлы, как следует из названия, можно и нужно кэшировать на клиенте. При перезагрузке, если что-то поменялось, у них изменятся названия и новая версия гарантировано загрузится.

Кроме того, есть базовый сценарий, который собирает все вместе. Ему обычно дается имя такого вида:

```
MyApp.nocache.js
```

Сам он не содержит логику приложения, только загрузчик. Средствами сервера необходимо запретить его кэширование. Тогда при очередном открытии (например, через Windows.open) браузер получит его новую версию, которая подтянет новые версии компонентов приложения. Если же файл не изменился, то компоненты будут взяты из кэша браузера.

Если приложение на  Spring-e, можно нарулить примерно так:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/MyApp.html" location="/MyApp.html" cache-period="0"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/MyApp/**/*.nocache.*" location="/MyApp/" cache-period="0"/>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. С кэшом тогда ещё поколдую, а вот сам переход сделал следующим образом:

public static native int goLocation(String location)
    /*-{ 
       $wnd.location = location;
    }-*/;